How to setup Datadog monitor that is aware of request body content
I would like to setup a monitor in Datadog that uses an alert threshold based on the content of the HTTP Request Body.
To be precise, my application clients send XML POST requests like this:
<Request>
 <accountId>100</accountId>
 <inputParam>A</inputParam>
</Request>

I'd like the monitor to trigger an alert if my application Response takes longer than 10 minutes (alert threshold) when accountId=100. But if the accountId is some value other than 100 then the alert threshold should be 5 mins.
Wondering what kind of monitor and query can accomplish this. I looked at the docs but they seem to point to tests looking at the Response rather than the Request. Would appreciate any pointers.

I see that in Trace Analytics there is a parameter like http.Request.content_length .  Perhaps there are similar ways to check for request body?
